# How do you represent a relation one tuple to 1?

Tags: uml

I have a situation where the key of two tables will map to one row of a third table.

For example, let's say that each combination of classroom and topic will map to one teacher.

How can I represent that any tuplet (classroom, topic) is a one to one relationship with a teacher ?

Comment: [`UML Association Class`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744466/when-to-use-uml-association-classes) may be the technical term you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply model that as an aggregation like so:

[image]

Using an association class like pointed out by @xmojmr would probably only make sense if there is some operation connected (as the posted link also states).

Whether you use a simple association or a composition between `Course` and `Teacher` depends on your domain. The shown way will fix it and a course only exists if all 3 parts are defined. Using a simple association will tell that a course virtually exists and can be held by an arbitrary teacher. Still then topic/class room relate as tuple to a teacher.