# How to convert from UML to java. Dotted line relationship

Tags: java, uml

I'm trying to convert UML to java, but, I don't know how to do this type of transformation:

[image]

I have Participant class:

```
public class Participant extends User {

    List<Competition> competitions;

    public Participant(String username, String password, String fullname) {
        super(username, password, fullname);
    }

    public Submission submitPrediction(Competition competition, float prediction) {
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Submission> getSumissions() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I have Competition:

```
public class Competition {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private float target;
    private boolean isActive;

    private Organizer owner;
    private List<Participant> participants;
    private Platform platform;

    public Competition(int id, String title, float target, boolean isActive, Organizer owner, List<Participant> participants, Platform platform) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.target = target;
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.participants = participants;
        this.platform = platform;
    }
    .......... all methods, getters/setters, ectc............
}
```

And Submission:

```
public class Submission {
    private int id;
    private SubmissionStatus status;
    private Date submitedAt;
    private float prediction;
    private float error;

    public Submission(int id, SubmissionStatus status, Date submitedAt, float prediction, float error) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.submitedAt = submitedAt;
        this.prediction = prediction;
        this.error = error;
    }
        .......... all methods, getters/setters, ectc............
}
```

But I don't know how to convert the dotted relation between the 3 classes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an association class. It is a shortcut for

[image]

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744466/when-to-use-uml-association-classes)

Comment: SO, if I dont understand wrong, that means, that (for example) instead of have in COmpetition, something like:` private Organizer owner;
    private List<Participant> participants;
    private Platform platform;` It "converts" to something like:  `private Organizer owner;
    private List<Submission> submissions;
    private Platform platform;`  Or  I don't delete
`private List<Participant> participants;`and I add the relation in both classes (just looking submission-competition)

Comment: Sorry, my Java is very limited. I replaced it by a drawing. Just imagine the missing attributes/methods from your diagram.

Comment: Just also added the role names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand perfect. I was messed up on how the roles will be.